# MaterialTimePicker AM and PM width position incorrect

Tags: java, android, kotlin, material-components-android

[image: Screenshot of problem]

I'm using Material Library version 1.4.0-alpha01.

I'm seeing the above when trying to display the time picker dialog. I tried version 1.3 and I am still seeing this.

Does anyone know how to fix the above so the AM/PM is in the correct position and width?

This is the code I'm using to display the Time picker dialog:

```
val picker =
                    MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
                            .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
                            .setHour(HOUR_OF_DAY)
                            .setMinute(MINUTE)
                            .setTitleText("Select time")
                            .build()

            picker.show(this.supportFragmentManager, "SelectStartTime")
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem the issue is with androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0-alpha2 upgrading to androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0-beta01 fixes this issue.

```
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0-beta01'
```

Probably had something to do with the following which was added back on beta01:

ConstraintLayout

- android:layout_width and android:layout_height are back being non-optional due to compatibility issues.

[Source](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/03/constraintlayout-210-beta-1.html)